# Load, Update and Save, or execute Insert/Update sql commands directly?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I've got this process which happens when a user wants to void a check.

Each Check contains multiple PayableCheck records, and multiple Error records

```
Check.CheckID = PayableCheck.CheckID
Check.CheckID = Error.CheckID
```

Each PayableCheck matches up with 1 Payable record.

```
PayableCheck.PayableID = Payable.PayableID
```

Each Payable corresponds with a Receipt or an Error

```
Error.PayableID = Payable.PayableID
Receipt.PayableID = Payable.PayableID
```

When a user voids a Check (given a Check ID#), I need to:

1. Set the Check status to V
2. Create another Check with negative of the original check's amount
3. Create another Error for each Error associated with the original check, each Error having the negative amount
4. Set the Active field to 0 for each PayableCheck linked to the original Check
5. Set each linked Payable to status O
6. Set each linked Error to status O, and each linked Receipt to status O

Am I better off loading everything in using Entity Framework and making the changes in C# and then saving, or is there a better approach using just sql updates and inserts?

Comment: I don't think there is a difference in efficiency if that's what you're asking.  If you started using entity framework, you should continue for consistency.  If you find it too convoluted in EF, you can create stored procedure.  That way you can make changes later on without having to recompile your code. Just my $0.02.

Comment: I'm using EF. I was just wondering which way would be easier to code and maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what you are changing the "easy route" is to load the data in to the context with EF, make your changes then call save changes.

That should result in pretty good SQL but it's hardly efficient if you have concerns about the size of the entities or amount of data you will be loading then the better approach would be to handle it directly in SQL and script a stored procedure, you can can still call that from EF of course.

Answer (score 2):

Better create a stored procedure in sql server and write all the sql's which should do the purpose.